# When did Abel publish his test for the convergence of series?

Tags: mathematics, calculus, real-analysis

Did Abel published of testing the convergence of series? If so, when did he published it. Also, did he offer a proof of the test? Or did he simply stated the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what we read in page 313 of the second English edition of K. Knopp's *Theory and applications of infinite series*, the test and its proof may have first appeared in the [Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik](https://eudml.org/journal/10147), vol. 1, p. 314, 1826.